# How to get the active tab URL in an e10s add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless, e10s, firefox-addon-overlay

For a toolbar button click, I need to get the URL address of the active tab.

But

```
window.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument
```

gets a `CPOW` error.

How can I get the URL location of the active tab URL within an e10s add-on?

Comment: What [kind of Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) are you making ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions), [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), [Bootstraped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), or [Overlay/XUL/Legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions))? Please [edit] the appropriate tag into your question.  From your use of `window.gBrowser` it is more likely to be Bootstraped, or Overlay/XUL/Legacy.

Comment: yes it is  Bootstraped, or Overlay/XUL/Legacy. I suppose I cant add new tags by myself?

Comment: You are always able to edit your own question, including adding or removing tags. I have added tags for bootstrapped/restartless and overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around at the objects available, and in the [source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/3ba5426a03b495b6417fffb872d42874edb80855/toolkit/modules/RemoteWebProgress.jsm#251), it looks like where you should get the URI for the active tab is:

**From the current [`nsIURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIURI):**

```
window.gBrowser.currentURI.spec
```

The object `window.gBrowser.currentURI` returns a [`nsIURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIURI) which has a number of properties from which you could get the URI, including:

```
[nsIURI].spec //Returns a string representation of the URI. 
[nsIURI].asciiSpec //The URI spec with an ASCII compatible encoding. 
[nsIURI].specIgnoringRef //Returns a string representation of the URI without the ref
                         //  (part after the #) portion.
```

You can also get the [`nsIURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIURI) for the current selected tab as:

```
window.gBrowser.selectedBrowser._documentURI
```

**From the `urlbar`:**
You could, of course, pull the URL out of the `urlbar`:

```
window.document.getElementById('urlbar').value
```

**Finding `window`:**
All of the above assume that you have set `window` appropriately to the currently active window.  For example, by doing something like:

```
    //  Add/remove a "/" to comment/un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
    /* Add-on SDK:
    let window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    //*/
    //* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm"); //Services
    let window=Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");        
    //*/
```

Comment: Makyen, same add-on but now I need to insert css tag into head element of active document by toolbar button. Is it possible for e10s without content script? Or should I ask new question?

Comment: @JohnBernard, It is a new question. However, you are correct in your belief that it would require a content script of some sort. The separation of the active document from background scripts is one of the primary effects on add-ons of multiprocess (e10s). Only a very limited amount of information (e.g. the URL as in above) is available to the background process without the use of a content script.

Comment: Thanks so much @Makyen. Appreciated.